# why is escaping necessary for find's regex?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Say I have 3 files and I want to exclude 2 of them from find.

```
/tmp/test/c
/tmp/test/a
/tmp/test/b
```

```
# works
find /tmp/test -type f -not -regex "/tmp/test/\(a\|b\)"

# does not work
find /tmp/test -type f -not -regex "/tmp/test/(a|b)"
```

Single or double quote do not seem to matter here.

Why is this the case? I would think no escaping is needed, as shell does not touch the regex as the regex is in quotes.

Comment: In all "languages", characters with two potential meanings (here: literal parenthesis or group delimiter) must be escaped for one of the meanings. Which one is chosen by escaping differs from one language to the other.

Comment: How would you include a literal parenthesis in your pattern?

Comment: ` -regextype egrep -regex "/tmp/test/(a|b)"` It has nothing to do with the shell, it is a regex thing.

Comment: Your `find` (I‘m guessing it‘s the GNU one) uses BRE syntax, unless you change it with `-regextype`.